# Getting a string value from a pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, loops

I have Pandas Dataframe with one pathetic column called PLZ and an index. I want to iterate through the whole column and extract ONLY the value of PLZ, which is a string. The result should look like "50492" since PLZ is german for zipcodes.

Construction of Dataframe:

```
Daten=pd.read_csv("Daten.csv",sep=",",decimal=".",header=0,
               names=["PLZ", "Bundesland","Kreis",])

distance =Daten[["PLZ"]]
```

Output:

[image: DataFrame]

My current code looks like this:

```
distance =Daten[["PLZ"]]

for row in tqdm(distance.itertuples()):
     
     distance2 = pd.concat(calc_dist("50674", column))
```

The desired output should be a value like "58439" for column.

The problem is: I get for the calc_dist line: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable - apparently I cant use column to retrieve my values. But I can't use the .values[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RykSp.png) property either because it raises the same problem. I can't use iloc because it does not work with strings. Loc does not work because it relies on .values[0] in the end. Even approaches without loops did not work, because I have no way to retrieve the value of the cell.

The error message for an example with loc:

[image: Error]

Comment: kindly add a source dataframe, with the expected output. You could include the code to generate the dataframe as well

Comment: Hi I dont know exactly what you mean by source dataframe, but i added the creation and a screenshot, as well as the whole error message. kind regards!

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to:

```
distance =Daten[["PLZ"]]


for i in tqdm(range(len(distance))):
     a=distance.loc[i]["PLZ"]
   
     calc_dist("50674", a)
```

This magically worked, calling the distance.loc function in another function seemed to be a bad idea. Now I just have to iterate through 2million samples which is kinda slow but well :)